# Django - How to edit and submit multiple forms individually then render back to the same page?

Tags: python, django, forms, logic

So I'm building this *learning log* app where users can create multiple topics. I'm trying to create a single page where users can edit/save changes/delete their topic names. My logic in the `edit_topic` view function is to display the original topics in forms with `save` and `delete` button, code below or feel free to check [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/LD8/learning_log):

views.py

```py
def edit_topics(request, topic_pk=None):
    '''edit existing topics mainly the names'''
    # modify the model data according to the request method and name
    if request.method == 'POST' and topic_pk != None:
        if 'save' in request.POST:
            topic_to_change = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=topic_pk)
            form = TopicForm(instance=topic_to_change, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
        elif 'delete' in request.POST:
            topic_to_delete = get_object_or_404(Topic, pk=topic_pk)
            topic_to_delete.delete()
        return redirect('learning_logs:edit_topics')

    # get the original/modified data passing to render
    topics = Topic.objects.all()
    topic_lst = []
    for topic in topics:
        form = TopicForm(instance=topic)
        topic_lst.append(form)
    context = {'topics': topics, 'topic_lst': topic_lst}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/edit_topics.html', context)
```

edit_topics.html

```html
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<section class="container">
    <h3>Topics you have created</h3>
    <ul class="">
        {% for form in topic_lst %}
        <li class="mb-5">
            <form class="d-flex align-items-center" 
action="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_topics' form.instance.pk %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">save</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" name="delete">delete</button>
            </form>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{% url 'learning_logs:topics' %}">Done</a>
</section>

{% endblock content %}
```

url.py

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name="learning_logs"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),



    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    path('topics/edit/', views.edit_topics, name='edit_topics'),



    path('new_topic/', views.new_topic, name='new_topic'),
    path('topic_<int:topic_pk>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
    path('topic_<int:topic_pk>/new_entry/', views.new_entry, name='new_entry'),
    path('topic_<int:topic_pk>/entry_<int:entry_pk>/', views.entry, name='entry'),
    path('topic_<int:topic_pk>/entry_<int:entry_pk>/edit_entry/', views.edit_entry, name='edit_entry'),
]
```

However, I think there might be some logic error, it keeps raising `NoReverseMatch(msg) django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'edit_topics' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/edit$']`

If I delete `form.instance.pk` in `edit_topics.html` file, no error is raised. But consequently, the `if` logic in the view function wouldn't take action... I'm fairly new to programming, I'm sure there're some logic errors as well --

I'm struggling with the `topic_pk` optional argument in the view function because I'm not sure how to pass it in correctly.

Ideally, I hope the users can edit, save or delete the topics on this page one by one, and after they click `save` or `delete` the page will redirect back to this view and render the updated topic text. At the end, when they are done, they can click the `Done` button at the end...

Please help! Thanks!!

Feel free to check [GitHub Repo for Learning_Log app](https://github.com/LD8/learning_log)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also include your `urls.py`. The problem is related to the url pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. `url.py` added. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your url like this:

```
path('topics/edit/', views.edit_topics, name='edit_topics'),
path('topics/edit/<int:topic_pk>/', views.edit_topics, name='edit_topic'),
```

And in html, change this line:

```
<form class="d-flex align-items-center" action="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_topic' form.instance.pk %}" method="POST">
                                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, what I did is that, have 2 urls point to same view, one with `topic_pk` and another is without it.

Comment: Hi @ruddra thanks for the reply but I tried your solution, `topics/` prompts `Reverse for 'edit_topics' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['topics/edit/(?P<topic_pk>[0-9]+)$']` which seems to have worsened the problem... because before this page can be shown properly. There are many topics to be displayed on `topics/` page and many forms to be displayed on `topics/edit/` page for users to edit, save changes and delete. urrggggg frustrating

Comment: **Worked like a charm!!! BRILL!!** Thank you soooo much @ruddra

Comment: Oh sorry @ruddra, could you take a look at the logic in the view function please? The delete button is working however the save button wouldn't save the edited content, instead, the original topic text is rendered again...

Comment: oh right got it... wrong name for the save button `<button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">save</button>` should be `name="save"`! Cheers man!